# Why does my jQuery fadeOut/remove get rid of the parent DOM element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items for example:

```
<li class="ui-state-default" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>test <a href="#" title="Delete" class="itemDelete">x</a></li>

$('.itemDelete').live("click", function() {

                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
```

All is ok. If I change it to

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });
```

It seems to remove the `<li>` ok but also the `<li>` above it. I've tried running the fade then the remove on separate lines but that appears to the user as if its just done a remove and not the fade.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue of what `this` refers to — in the callback, `this` is your faded element.  You want:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume this in the callback is the object that has been faded?

Answer (score 2):

You're removing the parent's parent. Change it to:

```
 $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); });
```